# Liferay control panel menu portlets

Tags: liferay

How does liferay list out the portlet to be shown in the control panel menu?
Can any body list the classes and JSP involved in the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to file in your liferay source at location : `\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\control_panel_menu\view.jsp`

You will get idea how liferay shows its control panel menu.

[Link](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/control_panel_menu/view.jsp) for code of this jsp.

Answer (score 0):

All of the portlets are saved in the portlet table while we deploy them. Then once the control panel is accessed then liferay loads all of the portlet which are having the control panel entry in them. For better explanation see the below code in

```
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl

@Override
public Set<Portlet> getControlPanelPortlets(long companyId, String category)
    throws SystemException {

    Set<Portlet> portletsSet = new TreeSet<Portlet>(
        new PortletControlPanelWeightComparator());

    if (Validator.isNull(category)) {
        return portletsSet;
    }

    List<Portlet> portletsList = PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortlets(
        companyId);

    for (Portlet portlet : portletsList) {
        String portletCategory = portlet.getControlPanelEntryCategory();

        if (category.equals(portletCategory) ||
            (category.endsWith(StringPool.PERIOD) &&
             StringUtil.startsWith(portletCategory, category))) {

            portletsSet.add(portlet);
        }
    }

    return portletsSet;
}

@Override
public List<Portlet> getControlPanelPortlets(
        String category, ThemeDisplay themeDisplay)
    throws SystemException {

    Set<Portlet> portlets = getControlPanelPortlets(
        themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), category);

    return filterControlPanelPortlets(portlets, themeDisplay);
}
```

The above code is called from the

```
\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\control_panel_menu\view.jsp 
Map<String, List<Portlet>> siteAdministrationCategoriesMap = PortalUtil.getSiteAdministrationCategoriesMap(request);
```

Help taken from [pankaj-kathiriya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/859518/pankaj-kathiriya) answer. Thanks for the same.

Comment: It was my answer, not comment :P

Comment: My bad, I should have written that as an answer. I had just putted the details in that answer. 
Anyway marked it as an answer. :-)